# Writing a text based ui in java, to manage the use of an AccountList class, can't make the constructor work

Tags: java

Given address, account and account list classes already made, I've been stuck with the constructor of my BankUI class for a few hours and I feel like I'm making a really basic mistake. The other classes compile properly but I get

```
constructor Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types; 
required: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The operator that you use here cannot be used for the type of value that you are using it for. You are either using the wrong type here or the wrong operator.
```

I would imagine this is something to do with the fact that my Account constructor is a bunch of Strings for name/account number etc. Just no idea where I'm going wrong and I've tried a few different combinations.

Also apparently my showAll has "incompatible types"? Really unsure about fixing these problems :/

```
public class BankUI
{
private Scanner keyboard;
private ArrayList accounts;
private Account account;

public BankUI()
{
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Account account = new Account();

}
 public void addAcc()
{
}
 public void getNumberOfAccs()
{
    System.out.println("There are" + Account.getNumberOfAccs + " accounts.");
}
public void showAll()
{
    for (Account account : accounts)
        System.out.println(account);
}

public void removeAcc()
{
}
```

Comment: Looks like `Account` constructor takes 4 String parameters and you aren't giving it any when you do `Account account = new Account();`. Also, your ArrayList should be given a type to work with like `ArrayList<Account>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Account` class requires 4 `String`s as constructor arguments, so for example `new Account("foo", "bar", "baz", "1337")`.

The first thing you should do is determine, what to pass as arguments and give these to the `BankUI` class as constructor arguments as well.

The second thing what I recognized is your initialization of your account in the constructor of your `BankUI`. Instead of writing `Account account = new Account();` I bet you want to init your field, which would be `account = new Account("your", "four", "strings", "here");`, like the line above.

Comment: Just tried it with the corresponding amount of strings for the account constructor and now it gives me incompatible types - http://puu.sh/d46ls/75e99d6a98.png

Comment: You're caling it with 6 parameters in your screenshot? Incompatible types may occur, if you have the wrong Account imported.

Comment: The constructor is fine now although it is probably wrong given that I still can't figure out any of the other methods, thanks for the help though, ended up putting down http://puu.sh/d4nrB/8d4e203383.png